# Angularjs ui-router, how to catch parameter's value within templateURL

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I wonder if I can catch the parameter's value like below:

```
    .state('form', {
         url: "/from/:formID",
         templateUrl: "forms/{{formID}}.html"
     });
```

I want to assign the parameter's value inside the templateURL. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do something like this  :

```
    templateurl : function($routeParams){
                  return "forms/" + $routeParams.formId + ".html" }
```

By using a function to return a value, you can inject logic in your routing.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the $interpolate service from AngularJS.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate